# Why are software license windows not resizable?

Tags: legal

In almost every software I ever installed on Windows, the EULA text is in a small non-resizable text area.

The text itself is also in small font, is not resizable and because there is a lot of it the scrollbar shrinks and only its arrow buttons are practically usable.

Usually there is no attempt to simplify navigation in the license or even display a table of contents.

My usual solution is to copy the text into a text editor. But today I found a software installer that lets me select the text of the license, but blocks copying.

To me the only understandable thing is to limit the width of text for easier reading, everything else seems arbitrary.

*What are the reasons for crippling the UI like this?
Or is it just an artifact of the past in MS Windows installers?*

*Is it maybe subtle nudging of the user to not bother reading the license?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From both a developer’s and product owner’s point of view, my best guess would be: it’s simply no priority.

Ask yourself the question:

- For two almost identical pieces of software, would you favour buying one over the other just because the license display during installation is nicer? I assume not.

On the other hand, software vendors are legally obliged to show the license to you—depending on jurisdiction—even if it is practically the same standard text as in 95% of your already installed applications.

Why then waste any resources (designers, developers, testers, etc.) on the license display – beyond the legal minimum and “how everybody else does it”?
Rather put that time/energy into a feature in the application that is more likely to be used (more than once).

The same goes the other way around: there is no point in making it harder for the user to read the license text. In your example where copying was not allowed, that was most likely unintentional since nobody ever tested it.

---

As per `jamesdlin`'s comment below, this might be especially true for Microsoft Windows:

> Additionally, on Windows, making resizable dialog boxes typically is a significant amount of work. It's not built into Win32. Consequently, most dialog boxes (not just license prompts) are not resizable.

Comment: Additionally, on Windows, making resizable dialog boxes typically is a significant amount of work.  It's not built into Win32.  Consequently, most dialog boxes (not just license prompts) are not resizable.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense. i thought the installer experience would factor in, but it is probably done by the IT department in companies and most users do not even see the installer after all.

Answer (score -3):

> Or is it just an artifact of the past in MS Windows installers?

Yup, you' ve guessed it right, for example, on macOS most programs have a better installation experience, just because their average user will pay them much more money..

> What are the reasons for crippling the UI like this?

I think it is all because of really bad design that Microsoft does not support at all, they are "solidly" standing for uwp apps, really, they do not care that much about their OS, they are just focusing more on cloud services, because that is much more profitable, and also they are just completely bored of designing it, every single time they actually do something, they just put it to uwp, which is pretty bad for most software dev's. When developers try do design something, it just takes them a lot of time, so they just hope that microsoft will make something in the future..

Comment: I'm not quite sure what UWP (or Microsoft) has to do with this; if these old third-party applications were to actually use UWP, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This answer appears to have a lot of bias, speculation, and emotion, but not much substance.